# zsh - change color for host and username

Tags: shell, zsh

I just switched from bash to zsh and now I am trying to find out, how to colorize the Username and Host to have different color shemes.
With bash my colorsheme looked like that:
(orange)user (blue)@ (red)hostname

I couldn't find any good guide or explanation on how to seperate this and when I look at my actual .zshrc

```
 if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
 PROMPT=$'%F{%(#.blue.green)}┌──${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)──}(%B%F{%(#.red.blue)}%n%(#..㉿)%m%b%F{%(#.    blue.green)})-[%B%F{reset}%(6~.%-1~/…/%4~.%5~)%b%F{%(#.blue.green)}]\n└─%B%(#.%F{red}#.%F{blue}$)%b%F{reset} '
 RPROMPT=$'%(?.. %? %F{red}%B⨯%b%F{reset})%(1j. %j %F{yellow}%B⚙%b%F{reset}.)'
```

I can't figure out, what could be the current user and host color.

Comment: Try `info zsh 'prompt expansion'`. You may need to install a `zsh-doc` package or equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> %F{%(#.red.blue)}%n
> ```

- `%n` expands to your account name, so the colour set immediately before that is what matters.
- `%F` expands to the control sequence that sets the foreground colour to whatever is enclosed by the braces, which can be a colour name such as `blue` amongst other things.
- `%(#.red.blue)` is a ternary prompt expansion, that tests the shell process's current user ID (specified by the `#`) against zero (by default), and expands to `red` for user ID zero and `blue` otherwise.

## Further reading

- `man zshmisc`
- "[Prompt Expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html)" *The Z Shell Manual*.  sourceforge.